# Show folder/files structure on mobile phone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, treeview

I'm trying to find a way to format a tree structure corresponding to a folder/files structure in a way similar with the "listview" included in jQuery Mobile. The problem is that for a folder a user may decide to see the included folders and files (this can be done very nice and easy with the listview), but also it can decide to see the folder properties.

Any idea about a possible structure (existent or which I could implement) that I could use to show the folder/files data on a mobile phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [split button list](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-split.html).  Clicking on the folder itself drills into it, but clicking the right hand button navigates to the folder properties.